# How to Integrate BIRT report engine with minimum jars?

Tags: java, birt

Currently i have integrated BIRT report engine with my Struts2 Application, which has around 80 Jars and 51MB in Size, Can any body help me to reduce the jars in terms of number or size, i am worried that more jars may occupy more Perm-gen Space and affect on performance.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

BIRT comes with support for all databases. So, keeping only the jars related to our database helps in getting rid of many jars.